# Operand Type Clash : Datetime is incompatible with text

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working and developing an application, but there's an error when I try to insert the data from the windows forms, and it triggers the operand clash. Been searching but not sure where to go.

```cs
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Get data from UI
        u.id = Convert.ToInt32(textKodeInvoice.Text);
        u.jenis_sewa = comboSewa.Text;
        u.lama_sewa = textboxtlama.Text;
        u.tanggal_mulai = tanggalPutus.Value;
        u.tanggal_sekarang = tanggalSekarang.Value;
        u.jenis_kontrak = comboKontrak.Text;
        u.tanggal_selesai = tanggalAkhir.Value;
        u.nomor_pelanggan = Convert.ToInt32(textIDpelanggan.Text);
        u.nama_pelanggan = textNamapelanggan.Text;
        u.nopol_mobil = textNopol.Text;
        u.jenis_mobil = textJenismobil.Text;
        u.nomor_driver = Convert.ToInt32(noDriver.Text);
        u.nama_driver = textNamadriver.Text;
        u.uang_mobil = Convert.ToDecimal(textUangmobil.Text);
        u.uang_security = Convert.ToDecimal(textDeposit.Text);
        u.unit_ke = Convert.ToInt32(textUnit.Text);
        u.periode_ke = Convert.ToInt32(textPeriode.Text);
        u.uang_supir = Convert.ToDecimal(textUangsopir.Text);
        u.uang_bbm = Convert.ToDecimal(textBBM.Text);
        u.jenis_faktur = comboFaktur.Text;
        u.jangka = Convert.ToInt32(textJangka.Text);
        u.uang_total = Convert.ToDecimal(textTotal.Text);
        u.bank = comboBank.Text;
        u.tanggal_kirim = tanggalKirim.Value;
        u.alamat_kirim = textAlamat.Text;
        u.keterangan = textKeterangan.Text;
        u.tanggal_putus = tanggalPutus.Value;
        u.alasan_putus = textAlasan.Text;

        //Get username of logged in user and user ID
        string loggedUser = frmLogIn.loggedIn;
        invoiceBLL usr = dal.GetIDFromUsername(loggedUser);
        u.added_by = usr.id;

        //Insert Data into Database
        bool success = dal.Insert(u);


        //If data is succesfully inserted then the value of success will be true
        if (success == true)
        {
            //Data Sucessfully Inserted
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been inserted.");
            clear();
        }
        else
        {
            //Failed to Insert Data
            MessageBox.Show("Fail to insert data.");
        }
        DataTable dt = dal.Select();
        dgInvoice.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Something wrong while inserting: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have tried searching on google, overflow and also some YouTube videos but I don't have any clue to help fix it.

The dal.Insert code is right down here

```
public bool Insert(invoiceBLL u)
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);

        try
        {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO tabel_transaksi (jenis_sewa, lama_sewa, tanggal_mulai, tanggal_sekarang, jenis_kontrak, jenis_faktur, jangka ,tanggal_selesai, nomor_pelanggan, nama_pelanggan, nopol_mobil, jenis_mobil, nomor_driver, nama_driver, uang_mobil, uang_security, unit_ke, periode_ke, uang_supir, uang_bbm, uang_total, bank, tanggal_kirim, alamat_kirim, keterangan, tanggal_putus, alasan_putus) VALUES (@jenis_sewa, @lama_sewa, @tanggal_mulai, @tanggal_sekarang, @jenis_kontrak, @jenis_faktur,@jangka ,@tanggal_selesai ,@nomor_pelanggan, @nama_pelanggan, @nopol_mobil,@jenis_mobil ,@nomor_driver, @nama_driver, @uang_mobil, @uang_security, @unit_ke, @periode_ke, @uang_supir, @uang_bbm, @uang_total, @bank, @tanggal_kirim, @alamat_kirim, @keterangan, @tanggal_putus, @alasan_putus)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jenis_sewa", u.jenis_sewa);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lama_sewa", u.lama_sewa);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal_mulai", u.tanggal_mulai);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal_sekarang", u.tanggal_sekarang);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jenis_kontrak", u.jenis_kontrak);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jenis_faktur", u.jenis_faktur);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jangka", u.jangka);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal_selesai", u.tanggal_selesai);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomor_pelanggan", u.nomor_pelanggan);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama_pelanggan", u.nama_pelanggan);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nopol_mobil", u.nopol_mobil);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jenis_mobil", u.jenis_mobil);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomor_driver", u.nomor_driver);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama_driver", u.nama_driver);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uang_mobil", u.uang_mobil);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uang_security", u.uang_security);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit_ke", u.unit_ke);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@periode_ke", u.periode_ke);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uang_supir", u.uang_supir);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uang_bbm", u.uang_bbm);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uang_total", u.uang_total);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bank", u.bank);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal_kirim", u.tanggal_kirim);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alamat_kirim", u.alamat_kirim);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keterangan", u.keterangan);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal_putus", u.tanggal_putus);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alasan_putus", u.alasan_putus);

            conn.Open();

            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // If the query is executed successfully,
            // then the value to rows will be greater than 0 
            // else it will be less than 0
            if (rows > 0)
            {
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return isSuccess;
    }
```

I also used stack trace but it shows error on line 0

Comment: On which line exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @MindSwipe i'm not sure which line that is, is there any function that i can insert to find the line?

Comment: @Chetan It'll summon a prompt "Operand type clash: datetime is incompatible with text", there's no reference on which line

Comment: Also on the SSMS I used datetime format for datetime picker on my forms

Comment: Ahh, you're connecting to a database, then the problem is more than likely in your `dal.Insert` method, more specifically with your SQL query, you're probably constructing that incorrectly

Comment: let me give you the dal.insert method maybe there's a clue there @MindSwipe

Comment: Clearly one of your columns is `text` and you are passing a date. Why would you be using `text` for a date column?

Comment: Now I see, that's my mistake thank you for pointing out the mistake for me @Charlieface

Comment: Last time i checked, It's 2023, there's very little reason to use TEXT columns at all

Comment: Not related to your issue but [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).